# Multichoice fields with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-2010, dynamic-linq, linq-to-sharepoint

I'm making a SP2010 page where user can filter items by their phase (It's a multichoice field). For performance reasons and the nature of the filters I had to resort to System.Linq.Dynamic to make this query.

I've tried the following (this is not real code but exemplifies what I'm doing):

```
var lstObjects = new List<object>();
var query = "Phase = @0 ";
lstObjects.Add(Phase.Value);

context.myList.Where(query,lstObjects.ToArray());
```

This works if the item has only one phase and is the one being filtered. If the item has multiple phases (like Phase 1 and 2) and I filter by Phase 1, it must show. How can I filter the multichoice fields?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the type of the object "Phase.Value" is a flag enum that was generated using SPMetal.

Answer (score 0):

Try `context.myList.Where(m=>lstObjects.Contains(m.Phase))`  or something in that context.
If this isn't the solution you are looking for please provide with more information on what you mean with "Multi Phases"

a.e, does the user get to select multiple phases or does the object have mutliple phases, or both?

[edit]

I'm not real familiar with dynamic linq but I assume this could be a solution:

```
var lstObjects = new List<object>();
var query = "Phase == {0}";
lstObjects.Add(Phase.Value);
for (int i = 1; i < Phase.Count; i++)
{ 
    query += string.Format(" || Phase == {0}", i);
}

context.myList.Where(query,lstObjects.ToList());
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < Phase.Count; i++)
{ 
    if (i > 0) { query+= " || "; }
    query += string.Format("Phase == {0}", lstObjects[i].Value);
}
context.MyList.Where(query);
```

Let me know if this works.

[/edit]

Comment: The object can have multiple phases but you can only filter by one. However the query has to be with dynamic Linq because theres others filters and in order to have best performance.

Comment: Can't say I fully understand you. Does the m object (in my example) have multiple phases or does the lstObjects have multiple phases or both ?